# How to replace the contents of a cell based on row header?

Tags: string, excel, vba, search, concatenation

I need to search every cell in row 1 (a1 to dv1) for the instance where "doc1" is followed in the subsequent cell in that row by "doc2."  Then I need to concatenate the contents of what's in the cell one row below the cell containing "doc1" with what's in the cell one row below the cell containing "doc2", separated by a comma, and replacing the text in what's in the cell below the cell containing "doc1".

So, for example, if a1 has "doc1" and b1 has "doc2" and a2 has "7" and b2 has "8", then I need a2 to be replaced with "7, 8".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Amy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in VBA - you can just copy and paste this in a new module in VBA (backup your spreadsheet first), then run it (with F5).  To get to VBA fast, use alt-F11.  I've left my MSGBOX statements in the code commented out.  Also, the code goes until DW1 so it can finish DV1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Doc1_Doc2_Merge()

    Dim CurrCol As Integer
    Dim CurrRow As Integer
    Dim NewValue As String
    Dim EndCol As String

    For CurrRow = 1 To 50 Step 2 '(assume 50 rows - skip 2 lines each time)
       CurrCol = 1

       EndCol = "$DW$" & Trim(Str(CurrRow))
       While Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol).Address <> EndCol

           'MsgBox Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol).Address & " " & Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol).Value

           If InStr(Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol).Value, "doc1") > 0 Then
               ' look at next cell
               If InStr(Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol + 1).Value, "doc2") > 0 Then
                   If Trim(Cells(CurrRow + 1, CurrCol + 1).Value) <> "" Then
                       NewValue = Cells(CurrRow + 1, CurrCol).Value & "," & Cells(CurrRow + 1, CurrCol + 1)
                       'MsgBox "New Value is " & NewValue
                       Cells(CurrRow + 1, CurrCol).Value = NewValue
                   End If
               End If

           End If

           CurrCol = CurrCol + 1
       Wend
    Next CurrRow

End Sub
```

Here are test results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  This doesn't seem to be working properly yet.  Does it matter that the strings include "doc1" and "doc2" but don't "equal" doc1 and doc2?  Also, should Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value = "doc2" instead be: Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).String = "doc2"?  Thanks!

Comment: From your question, I thought they were hard coded values of doc1 and doc2 - I will update my code in a sec with if the values "contain" doc1 and doc2.  And .Value works - don't know about .String

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thanks!

Comment: One more question: if I only want the concatenation if the cell below doc2 isn't blank, is this the right code to insert? If (Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value) > 0 Then...

Comment: Close - since it's a string and if you don't want blanks either, try if Trim(cells(1,CurrCol+1).value) <> "" then

Comment: Sorry--this doesn't seem to be working properly.  I'm still getting the concatenation even when I include the Trim line.  This is what I have: If InStr(Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value, "Doc2") > 0 Then
                If Trim(Cells(1, CurrCol + 1).Value) <> "" Then
                    NewValue = Cells(2, CurrCol).Value & ", " & Cells(2, CurrCol + 1)
                '   MsgBox "New Value is " & NewValue
                    Cells(2, CurrCol).Value = NewValue
                End If
            End If

Comment: Redid the code - see the main answer - I tested it and it worked

Comment: One more question on this: if I have multiple lines of data, how can I add a loop so that the merging of doc numbers happens for all the cells in the column?  Is this a "for" loop?

Comment: Thanks.  This is not quite what I meant.  The header with "doc1" and "doc2" is only in the first row--not every other row.  Does that mean that the While loop should get moved down?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the layout of your data?  Doesn't have to be real data - I just can't picture what it looks like